# PHP Class inheritance and static members, the proper way of doing things

Tags: php, inheritance, static-members

I'm writing a lightweight ORM that can map database columns to instance fields with different names

eg.

**Database**

- userid
- username
- anotherpoorlynamedfield

**Object**

- user_id
- username
- another_poorly_named_field

To do this my original design was something like this

```
abstract class DbObj {
    /* In a subclass the author would provide the mapping of fileds
     * from the database to the object
     * e.g.
     * array('userid' => 'user_id', 'username' => 'username'....
     */
    protected static $db_to_obj = array();

    /* This would be auto popuplated from $db_to_obj in reverse */
    protected static $obj_to_db = array();

    /* Many Methods truncated... */

    /* Used by magic methods to make sure a field is legit */
    public function isValidField($name) {
         return in_array(strtolower($name), self::$db_to_obj);
    }
}
```

Then I subclass this out

```
class Cat extends DbObj {
     protected static $db_to_obj = array(
         'catsname' => 'name',
         'itsage' => 'age'
     );
}
```

The `isValidField` method does not work as expected. Using a debugger or a good ol fashioned `var_dump` you will find that the value of `self::$db_to_obj` is that of the parent class. I would understand this if `isValidField` was `static`, but it is not. It does have a `$this` pointer and it does know its class.

Is there a workaround for this behaviour or a better architecture to use?

Comment: [ORM == anti-pattern](http://seldo.com/weblog/2011/08/11/orm_is_an_antipattern/), [`static` == harmful](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0103_static_considered_harmful.html) ... I would reconsider what you're trying to do.

Comment: Agreed on the ORM bit, but if you aren't greenfielding an application and are trying to transform it slowly, then you gotta work with what you've got. Thanks for the info on static, but I feel like there are some design patterns where it is the best fit.

Comment: Feel free to use `static`, it just keeps you from enjoying the benefits of object orientation. `static` is class-oriented programming, not OOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
public function isValidField($name) {
  $class = get_class($this);
  return in_array(strtolower($name), $class::$db_to_obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't create variables which are protected and static at the same time when using inheritance.

And if you use inheritance, you can/should do something like:

```
parent::isValidField($name) {
  // code here
}
```